About Differentiability in geometric definition of tangent space
I have a question about the definition of the tangent space which confuses me a lot.
For the geometric definition of the tangent space $T_xM$ at the point x for a differentiable manifold M we have that the set of smooth curves $\alpha:(-\epsilon,\epsilon) \to M$ satisfy $\alpha(0)=x$. Then we define an equivalence class on these curves and call the classes to be the elements of the tangent space.
Now this definition gives me some struggles. We say two curves $\alpha,\beta$ are equivalent if for a chart at x $\varphi$ on M
$$
(\varphi \circ \alpha)'(0) = (\varphi \circ \beta)'(0).
$$
Is it then part of the definition that the composition has to be differentiable because, as I see it, a priori it is not clear that $\varphi \circ \alpha$ whill actually be differentiable at 0 because $\varphi$ is just a homeomorphism.
Moreover, the definition of a differentiable manifold only tells us that transition maps are differentiable but says nothing about maps like $\varphi \circ \alpha$.

This is what it means for $\alpha$ to be smooth.

Who says that $\varphi$ is just a homeomorphism? The charts of a smooth atlas of a manifold are smooth maps with respect to that atlas, almost tautologically.

The concept of smoothness was originally introduced for maps between open subsets of Euclidean spaces. This is the subject of multivariable calculus.
The concept was extended to maps between smooth manifolds (using the given smooth structures).
"Extended" means that

Open subsets $V \subset \mathbb R^n$ are smooth manifolds in a canonical way. $V$ has a canonical smooth atlas consisting of the single chart $id_V : V \to V$, and this atlas generates the smooth structure on $V$.

For maps $f : V \to W$ between open subsets of Euclidean spaces smoothness in the sense of multivariable calculus agrees with smoothness in the more general "smooth manifold" sense.


A look to Another definition of a smooth map between manifolds may be useful.

It is not clear that $φ∘α$ whill actually be differentiable at $0$ because $φ$ is just a homeomorphism.

You are right, charts are just homeomorphisms. However, the domain $U$ of a chart $\varphi : U \to U' \subset \mathbb R^n$ is an open subset of $M$ and thus inherits a smooth structure from $M$. It has a canonical smooth atlas consisting of the single chart $\varphi$. The smooth structure on $U$ consists of all charts on $M$ whose domain is contained in $U$.
With this smooth structure on $U$ the chart $\varphi$ is a smooth  map (actually a diffeomorphism between smooth manifolds). The composition $\varphi \circ \alpha$ is therefore a smooth map between smooth manifolds (which are open subsets of Euclidean spaces).
However, we do not really need the smoothness of $\varphi$. What does it mean that $\alpha$ is smooth?
By definition it means that for arbitrary charts $\psi$ around $0$ in $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$ and $\varphi$ around $x$ in $M$ the composition $\varphi \circ\alpha \circ \psi^{-1}$ is smooth in the sense of multivariable calculus. For $\psi$ we may take the identity on $(-\epsilon,\epsilon)$, thus $\varphi \circ\alpha$ must be smooth.
The expression $(\varphi \circ \alpha)'(0)$ is the usual componentwise derivative of a map $(-r,r) \to U' \subset \mathbb R^n$, i.e. a vector in $\mathbb R^n$.
